# Ambiguity of meaning of for in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> Learning everying at once is too confusing.
>   The post concludes with tips for what to learn next.

Last sentence is in trouble. I think for in the sentence could have two meanings. To clearify two mearnings:

1. Tips that recap what you've been learning on the post is provided at the end of the post, so that you are not perplexed with the things you will learn on the next. (organizaing your mind with the tips before the next)
2. Tips about what to learn next is provided at the end of the post.

Which meaning is correct? Or Both are not valid?

Comment: It means the post ends with advice on what areas of study to focus on next. It is unambiguous.

Comment: "for" means "regarding" or "about" in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 is correct. "tips for what to learn next" are usually not a recap, they simply point you to other areas or subjects that you should learn next. These tips are some sort of a guide that leads you from one part to the next.